# Unable to authenticate and login with Selenium Webdriver on my Virtual Machine

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, webdriver

After looking through various [sources](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/handling-login-popup-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java/), it seems that I have to use this syntax: https://username:password@URL to automate login for the following [Authentication Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z7uS.png).

This format seems to work on my local Mac environment and I am successfully able to pass my test case and retrieve the elements that I am looking for with the following code:

```
   chrome_options = Options()
   chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
   chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
   driver = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path="/Users/username/Downloads/chromedriver")
   url = "https://" + "username" + ":" + "password" + "@" + "url"
   driver.get(url) 
   print(driver.title)
   text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/main/div/div/div/form/button").text
   print(text)
```

However, when I run the same code on the production VM, I am unable to sign in. I get the following error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/main/div/div/div/form/button"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.114)
```

Note: the username contains an "@" symbol because it is an email address. I understand that the syntax for authentication "https://" + "username" + ":" + "password" + "@" + "url" contains an "@" symbol. This is what I believe is causing the error and not allowing me to sign in. But I don't know why this same format works on my local machine but not my VM. Is there any fix or workaround? The version of chromedriver on my VM is installed from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/91.0.4472.19/chromedriver_linux64.zip. Could it be that the Linux Chromedriver doesn't allow "@" in the username while the mac chromedriver does?

Comment: what is the result of print(driver.title) in this case. would you please complete logs

Comment: It requires 3 steps - launch with URL authenticator, Create cookie to save session, launch without login credentials - to login in headless chrome on a Linux machine. Solution provided in post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54461809.

Comment: @ErrorHunter print(driver.title) returns no results because it is just a blank page with the authentication popup visible.

Comment: Ok, so that mean page itself has a issue in loading and given Unable to locate element error doesn't really making sense because error/issue is before line